# UK Travellers to Australia with pending visa subclass 100 on eVisitor

Tags: visas, australia, uk-citizens

I'm an Australian citizen sponsoring my (British) partner and step children for a visa subclass 100. We expect that this will be granted some time mid December 2014 to mid-January 2015 but have no way of knowing exactly when.

For a bunch of reasons, I'd like them to come out and join me in September and believe that they can do this on an eVisitor however that would mean leaving Australia after 3 months. So if they arrive on September 1st they would need to leave on December 1st.

My question is, could they leave to NZ for a long weekend and then come back to Australia for a second 3 month visit? The eVisitor seems to allow multiple 3 month stays within a 12 month period but doesn't seem to stipulate whether there are limits on where you go to between those three month periods - does anyone know if there are such limits ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing is known as a "**visa run**".  Australia does not have a set limit for how many times or how long in total you can stay in the country on tourist visas like eVisitor, and it does not ban back-to-back entries on a tourist visa, so visa runs are possible -- [some stories here](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/australasia-pacific-australia-new-zealand-antarctica/Australia/re-entry-to-australia-on-tourist-visa?page=1).

However, tourist visas are meant for *tourism*, which is clearly not what your partner & children would be doing in Australia.  Whether they'd accept "hanging around, supported by Aussie husband, while we wait for visa" as an acceptable reason is unclear.  Immigration has the final say in whether they get in or not, and may suspect that your partner is working.

The safer and cheaper approach would be to approach Immigration towards the end of your three-month stay and ask for an extension of a month or two, which are ([anecdotally](http://www.expatforum.com/expats/australia-expat-forum-expats-living-australia/28509-extending-my-tourist-visa.html)) fairly freely granted.